# Configure LXC to use specific DNS server instead of DNSMASQ

Tags: lxc, dnsmasq, unbound

Out of the box, my LXC containers connect to a running instance of dnsmasq, which is started with the `lxc-net` service.

In my case, I am running a local unbound DNS server that connects to a thing called ncdns which lets me browse .bit domains that are registered via Namecoin.

The two of these conflict.  My lxc containers depend on `dnsmasq` for DNS, which runs on port 53.  At the same time my `unbound` server must run on port 53 in order for me to reach .bit domains.  (see the comments on [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1014992/bind-on-different-port-with-linux) for the unlikelihood of being able to include a nameserver in resolv.conf using a nonstandard port; I also asked on an IRC channel and basically learned that pointing resolv.conf to a DNS server on a nonstandard port is basically not possible).

So what I need to do is create a combined DNS server that supports LXC's stuff and can also resolve .bit domains, and run THAT on port 53.

It may be assumed that my `unbound` server recursively resolves .bit domains, and forwards all other domains to my router, so it can effectively resolve all domains.

Questions are as follows:

1: How do you tell lxc-net NOT to start dnsmasq?

2: I assume `unbound` won't just work as the DNS server for my LXC containers without further configuration.  How do I configure `unbound` so that it does what `dnsmasq` does for my lxc containers?  (An answer to this question could be either the location of the dnsmasq conf files that it uses when started by lxc-net (which I have not yet found) so that I can attempt to copy that configuration under unbound, or some other documentation that has the same information as the dnsmasq conf files used by lxc-net)

Comment: Found some stuff, looked in `/etc/init.d/lxc-net`, that file simply loads `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lxc/lxc-net` and that is what starts dnsmasq.  As far as I can tell there's no conf file used by dnsmasq, just command line arguments passed to it from the lxc-net script.  Unfortunately I see no way to disable dnsmasq, other than modifying that script so that it doesn't start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I think I got it.  I'll accept this answer, but mark my words I'll post another question if down the road this turns out not to have worked.

I'm still running 3 (!) DNS servers on this computer: `dnsmasq` as it came with LXC (not quite "as it came", see below), along with `ncdns` the Namecoin DNS server and `unbound`.

Again, I can only run 1 DNS server on port 53, so I have to choose one or the other for that port.  I can either take my `unbound` setup and extend it to do what `dnsmasq` does, or vice versa.  Because dnsmasq appears to already be intricately configured to work with LXC, and also serves as a DHCP server which unbound cannot do, I decided to take it as the starting point.

I created a `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` file with the following content:

```
listen-address=127.0.0.1
resolv-file=/etc/resolv.dnsmasq.conf
server=/bit./127.0.0.1#5301
```

The first line enables `dnsmasq` to listen to my local address, resolving names for not just LXC containers but my PC as well.  The second line tells dnsmasq to use a special resolv file, which I copied and pasted from resolv.conf (and which, in case any one cares, points to my router's IP).  The third and last line adds a `.bit` stub domain for which requests are forwarded to my `unbound` server running on port 5301.

I also changed my resolv.conf file to simply

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

so that all DNS lookups are fulfilled by `dnsmasq`.